How to view only the direct items in a Postman folder?
Looked into this but was unable to find anything. This used to be a feature in the older Postman versions, but I can't find a setting to turn it on back now.
Take the following API collection structure:
-- Operations
   `-- Parameters      <-- Currently opened in Postman
       |-- GET API 1
       |-- GET API 2
       `-- GET API 3

Earlier I could easily see the 3 requests on the right side.
Now I have to use the tree style navigator on the left which I find considerably slow to use because sometimes it has MANY requests in inner folders which may be expanded.
Basically I just want to be able to:

View the current items in a folder, not any of their children.
Be able to Jump one level of the tree structure one at a time (this is already doable, ignore)

Screenshot attached of how it used to be like.

